# TypeError: fit() missing 1 required positional argument: 'X'

Tags: python-3.x

The code i tried is-

```
X = dataset.iloc[:,:].values
from sklearn.preprocessing import Imputer
imputer = Imputer(missing_values = 'Nan', strategy = 'mean', axis = 0)
imputer = Imputer.fit(X[:,2:52])
X[:,2:52] = imputer.transform(X[:,2:52])
```

The error i am getting is -
*TypeError: fit() missing 1 required positional argument: 'X'*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `imputer = Imputer(...)` creates new instance of `Imputer`. When you want use this instance you just call it like `imputer.method(args)`. So the correct usage should be something like this:

```
X = dataset.iloc[:,:].values
from sklearn.preprocessing import Imputer
imputer = Imputer(missing_values = 'Nan', strategy = 'mean', axis = 0)
imputer.fit(X[:,2:52])
X[:,2:52] = imputer.transform(X[:,2:52])
```

Comment: TypeError: ufunc 'isnan' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''  ,  This is the error after modification

Comment: @RahulRamaswamy Looks like another problem not related to this question. Please create a new one with full error traceback.